# When is $TERM replaced from "dumb" to "xterm"?

Tags: command-line, bash

I added a line to `$HOME/.profile` just for interest.

```
echo ${TERM:-"\$TERM isn't set."} > $HOME/term/.profile
```

After the next login, I saw a word `dumb` in `$HOME/term/.profile`.

```
$ cat term/.profile 
dumb
```

Then I opened `gnome-terminal` and typed `echo $TERM`. The result was `xterm`.

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

When is `$TERM` replaced from `dumb` to `xterm`?

I know there are some similar questions and saw them, but I couldn't understand them enough for finding the answer.

There is neither `.bash_profile` nor `.bash_login` in `$HOME`.

And this is `who` command's output:

```
$ who am i
cul8er   pts/1        2015-11-25 05:31 (:0)
```

OS: Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Unless you're telling GNOME Terminal to run login shells, it doesn't run `.profile`.

Comment: I don't want to know set TERM to dumb when I invoke gnome terminals. I'm  learning linux/Unix and just confused that I can't find the point TERM variable is changed when or until gnome terminals are invoked.

Comment: It would be somewhere in the code of GNOME Terminal. It is a proper terminal emulator, unlike whichever program was using `TERM=dumb`. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I don't complain TERM isn't dumb when gnome terminals are invoked. I'm a beginner  and learning linux. There is a part that explains TERM in my textbook(Unix Power Tools), so I tried to check how the variable is used just for interest. So if its answer is "Gnome terminal set it", that's ok to me. But I wanted to get a bit more concrete answer  if it's possible, maybe because I'm a programmer and curious about issues like this.

Comment: If you're a programmer, have you tried using the source?

Comment: Not yet because  I didn't expect  this question need to look at source code of gnome terminal. I thought there was a script file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `dumb` that you're seeing is probably set [by `systemd`](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-August/021699.html) for LightDM (which sources `.profile` when you login, see `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session`).

The value `xterm` is set by GNOME Terminal, or, rather [the VTE library](https://github.com/GNOME/vte) that it uses. GNOME Terminal itself doesn't provide a way to change the setting, unlike other VTE-based terminals like XFCE Terminal. See [`src/pty.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/blob/vte-0-28/src/pty.c#L1693):

```c
/**
 * VtePty:term:
 *
 * The value to set for the TERM environment variable just after
 * forking.
 *
 * Since: 0.26
 */
g_object_class_install_property
        (object_class,
         PROP_TERM,
         g_param_spec_string ("term", NULL, NULL,
                              "xterm",
                              G_PARAM_READWRITE |
                              G_PARAM_STATIC_STRINGS));
```